# Clearing values on gsheet with script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to clear some values in a defined named range taking into account also other value from another defined range of the same size. Here is my code below.

I get a Out of range on rng_stages.getCell(i,0).clearContent()
I suspect I no longer have a pointer to the sheet itself. As you can see I am not familiar with cell value assignment.

Does onOpen only triggers when the workbook opens or it also triggers each time a sheet is open in the same workbook? The named ranges only exist in the first sheet.

Here is the code:

```
function onOpen() {
   var rng_stages = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('ClaimStages');
   var rng_levels= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('ClaimLevels');
   var arr_stages = rng_stages.getValues();
   var arr_levels = rng_levels.getValues();

   for (var i = 0; i < arr_stages.length; i++) {
      if ((arr_stages[i][0] == 'Approved') && (arr_levels[i][0] == -1)) {
          rng_stages.getCell(i,0).clearContent()
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Kindly provide a sample spreadsheet

Comment: Unfortunately my company prevents sharing Google docs outside the company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const rng_stages = ss.getRangeByName('ClaimStages');
  const rng_levels = ss.getRangeByName('ClaimLevels');
  const arr_stages = rng_stages.getValues();
  const arr_levels = rng_levels.getValues();
  for (let i = 0; i < arr_stages.length; i++) {
    if ((arr_stages[i][0] == 'Approved') && (arr_levels[i][0] == -1)) {
      rng_stages.getCell(i+1, 1).clearContent()
    }
  }
}
```

[Range.getCell(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getCell(Integer,Integer))

Rows and Columns begin at 1

Comment: Thx! This works now using a starting index at 1. However, I was hoping that the script would execute each time I access the sheet. Instead it only runs when I refresh or reopen the whole gsheet document. If the gsheet

Comment: Thx! However, I was hoping that the script would execute each time I access the sheet. Instead it only runs when I refresh or reopen the whole gsheet document. I probably will not deploy since most of my users leave their workbook open in their browser for days. Any ideas of a good hook to enable execution when the specific sheet is shown or to force periodic workbook refresh. I could also use onChange event instead but this seems like an overkill that could slow down the whole sheet since it will execute each time a different cell is selected.

Comment: Time Based Triggers

Comment: Yep that might just be sufficient. Thx!

Comment: They're are some things that being on a shared server just can't replace over having a spreadsheet running on a powerful personal computer.  One of them is unlimited triggers to do just about anything your heart desires.